# Interconnect a chatbot from DialogFlow and one from Watson

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, ibm-watson, facebook-chatbot, sap-conversational-ai

For those who don’t know, [Proximity](http://www.gogowego.com) is a plateform to interconnect and create bots. 
A metabot connects bots from different technologies to form a unique “big” bot.
For example , I connected a bot from Recast and one from DialogFlow together to get a metabot.

When i connect a bot from IBM Watson , i get a an unknown error message and nothing appears on the screen :(

One of my friends has already succeded to connect a chatbot from watson in his metabot so i don’t undersatnd why it isn’t working for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your filling the right access info. Ex :

workspace_id : "ahdhvc-ffdf ..."

username : "fdfhjh-aasd"

password : "ahdhvcffdf"

If your bot is hosted on Germany region "https://gateway-**fra** ..." or others you must to specify the  url too.